# How to format text containing underscore to italic style?

Tags: support, markdown

How to format a text containing underscore (like for instance **"A_B"**) to italic style ?
Here's an example which fails in parsing somehow (from a quick test just on underscore):

*A_B*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTML tag (`<i>`),

```
<i>**A_B**</i>
```

produces ***A_B***. The underscore makes Markdown fail to interpret the markup as intended.

Answer (score 13):

I have changed (almost rewritten) the Markdown regular expressions for bold and italics: [client-side change](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=39afe9b2d865cce8e1aa0652215259167169006c), [server-side change](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=fb4e4b17de52d404e6c4d3f7fefd712f3b44febb). These will be in the next build.

They fix various issues, the major ones being:

1. Asterisks and underscores don't interfere with each other anymore. In particular, your `*A_B*` will look as expected.
2. Intra-word emphasis is *really* disabled. Asterisks and underscores [are not supposed to have any effect](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/) when they appear inside words, but in cases like `foo__bar__baz` and `2**5 + 4**3` they still  did.
3. `***text***` now renders as `<strong><em>text</em></strong>`, not incorrectly nested as `<em><strong>text</em></strong>`. This wasn't usually a user-visible problem (the browsers handle it fine), but could cause some weird-looking revision diffs, for example.

I have tested this change on 50,000 Meta posts (where every Markdown edge case that exists is exploited somewhere, so it's a good test bed). The only place where this made a difference that wasn't clearly positive was [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158932/question-banned-user-meta-review-queue), where the italicized footnote was created with `**We would...*`. The fact that this used to work was more an accident.

All other locations where I found a difference caused by this change are a definite improvement.

This already worked correctly in comments.

Comment: Is this why [URLs now have `_` percent encoded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229431/bug-due-to-overzealous-encoding-of-urls)? If that's a new change (the non-reserved `_` character being encoded to `%5f`) then that change broke Github links at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229144/115866) is why.