# Intra word markdown doesn't function properly when combining italic and bold

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

I mean, why can I w*r*i**t**e **i**n **this**w*ay*, (just bolding: `**wo**rd`, or just italicizing:`*wo*rd`), but I can't ***comb***ine bold and italic?

It works ***non-intra-word***, but doesn't work ***intra-***word.

**Is** *i*t a ***bu***g?

Comment: Related (and saying it works): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have ***combi***nation, just not using asterisks.

See here for an older post where markdown was significantly changed (re-written apparently)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/230506

Perhaps comment to Balpha about this ***iss***ue you found.

Comment: Accepting because it's a workaround anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `*` doesn't work if it is next to a punctuation mark or a number, and `**` counts as one:

> 123*456*789 `123*456*789`
>
> 123a*a456a*a789 `123a*a456a*a789`
>
> abc*def*ghi `abc*def*ghi`
>
> abc***def***ghi `abc***def***ghi`
>
> abc*'def*'ghi `abc*'def*'ghi`
>
> abc**def**ghi `abc**def**ghi`

Use HTML or `_` in the meantime:

> 123***456***789 `123<strong><em>456</em></strong>789`
>
> 123***456***789 `123**_456_**789`

[Reason behind this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works):

> 2. If a single or double asterisk is supposed to be interpreted as intra-word emphasis, it cannot have punctuation on one side; it actually must be inside a word. An example of an edge case this solves is
>
>    > It's a web*-based solution.
>    >
>    > *see Wikipedia for a definition of "web"
>
>    where the asterisks after "web" could cause unintended italicizing if there was a second asterisk in the same paragraph somewhere.

Comment: Hm, but what's the reason behind it?.. Bug again, or intentional?

Comment: @nicael Edited to explain