# Have I found a bug in the way that SE parses comments for bold markdown?

Tags: support, bug, markdown

In [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32409/set-and-shopt-why-two#comment471137_208244) I was trying to do "[intra-word emphasis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42250/167351)". It took me 3 tries and what I finally had to do is suboptimal. SE can choose whatever parsing rules they want. I won't debate my desire to emphasize a portion of a word in this thread. What I do think is a problem is that I expect that I can use the answer editor to preview my comment before copy-pasting it into the comment box (and get the same rendering).

I will add 3 comments to this question to demonstrate the differences between how comments and answers/questions are rendered.

### Code

```
1 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $**SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $BA**SHOPT**S.

2 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $<strong>SH</strong>ELL<strong>OPT</strong>S rather than $BA<strong>SHOPT</strong>S.

3 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $ **SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $ BA**SHOPT**S.
```

### Renderings

1 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $**SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $BA**SHOPT**S.

2 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $**SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $BA**SHOPT**S.

3 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $ **SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $ BA**SHOPT**S.

---

In case this behavior changes in the future, I want to document how it renders at the time of my asking.

[image: I hope the window and drop shadow make it more clear that this is an image and not...]

### What you should notice

- **It's not** that HTML doesn't render in attempt #2. The literal text displays consistently. That is by design and that is okay.
- **It is** that in attempt #1 the placement of the `$` changes the rendering. It seems to nullify the first `**` which in effect inverts what is bold and what is not.
- If it rendered the literal text, again I would say "that is by design and that is okay." But that is not the case.
- In attempt #3 it renders correctly in the comment the same as it does in the question because there is a space after the `$`.

### Why this is not a dupliacte

It has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112050/using-bold-or-italics-within-a-word-in-a-comment-does-not-work). The rendering example above demonstrates that it is not. In that question he states that the double asterisks show up in the comment. That may have been true at the time that he asked the question (I don't know because he didn't include a screenshot of the rendering), but it is not today. So, I'd suggest that it is not [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) but rather [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Here it is today:

[image: another screenshot]

Comment: 1 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $**SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $BA**SHOPT**S.

Comment: 2 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $<strong>SH</strong>ELL<strong>OPT</strong>S rather than $BA<strong>SHOPT</strong>S.

Comment: 3 Ugh! That is even more confusing. My brain wants to associate `shopt` with $ **SH**ELL**OPT**S rather than $ BA**SHOPT**S.

Comment: Your second option is by-design - comments only support a subset of the Markdown available in posts. You cannot use HTML in comments.

Comment: Cannot use HTML in comments. Understood. Only included for completeness.

Comment: The important thing to note is that in attempt #1 it does emphasize mid word, but it does it **wrong**. If it display all the double asterisks I'd have assumed that it was by design, but this is just wrong.

Comment: not "m**a**derator nominations"  As you can see, the issue reported in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112050/using-bold-or-italics-within-a-word-in-a-comment-does-not-work has been resolved because you see a bold letter **a** and not double asterisks.

Comment: Using `$ **` it works: $ **bold**plain**bold**plain**bold**plain**bold**plain Using `$**` it fails: $**bold**plain**bold**plain**bold**plain**bold**plain Other than the space after the dollar sign the code is the same for both, but the rendering is inverted.